# I can't install Mariadb on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server, mariadb, vps

I am trying to install Mariadb on VPS on Ubuntu 22.04 but the following error is displayed:
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest first to uninstall the package

```
sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server
```

and try to reinstall

you can follow digital ocean steps

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

Remove previously installed packages and check above URL.

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-focal-fossa/